# AngularJS - Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: $soapProvider

Tags: angularjs, soap, wsdl, angularjs-service

I am trying to make a simple service call using SOAP services in AngularJS based on this page http://mcgivery.com/soap-web-services-angular-ionic/

But I am getting this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24soapProvider%20%3C-%20%24soap%20%3C-%20CallService

this is my code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="soapclient.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.soap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Call Web Service - Test" ng-click="CallService();" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.factory("CallService", ['$soap',function($soap){
    var base_url = "http://10.0.0.70:8080/WS_usrService/WS_usr?wsdl";

    return {
        getAll: function(){
            return $soap.post(base_url, "getAll");
        }
    }
}])

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, CallService) {
    CallService.getAll().then(function(response){
        $scope.response = response;
    }, function(){
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });

})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that Angular cannot find the service `$soap`, which is defined on the module `angularSoap`.

According to the [official guide](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap), add the module dependency as:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoap'])
```

Comment: Thank you Shaojiang Cai, that solved the problem!

But now I am getting a new error :(

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.0.0.70:8080/WS_usrService/WS_usr?wsdl?wsdl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
soapclient.js:158 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Comment: Hi @Margaret. I think you need to google for solution first, then post another question if necessary.

Comment: Thank you I did solve, it adds automaticaly the ?wsdl parameter so I deleted it form the base_url

Answer (score 0):

All the services and controllers are boot strapped in "myApp" in your case.

You have not defined the $soap , while bootstraping the application.

It must be like this `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoap'])`